# Capybara visit not working , ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am new in testing with capybara, while writing my first very simple test I got an error and just don't know how to fix it

```
Failure/Error: visit root_path
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
     (in ../app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
```

Here is my simple test:

```
 require 'spec_helper'

 feature "the login process" do

  scenario "signs me in" do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_content "Willkommen!"
  end
end
```

Here is the interesting part of my routes :

```
                root GET    /                               root_pages#home
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)       devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
```

My spec_helper.rb

```
require 'rubygems' 
ENV["Rails_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'database_cleaner'

require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

RSpec.configure do |config|
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
config.before(:suite) do 
  begin 
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    FactoryGirl.lint
  ensure
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
# rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
# assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
# assertions if you prefer.
config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
  # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
  # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
  # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
  #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
  #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
  # ...rather than:
  #     # => "be bigger than 2"
  expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
 config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
  # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
  # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
  # `true` in RSpec 4.
  mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
```

I hope this is everything you will need. If something is missing, please comment below. Thanks for your help.

So here is my root_page_controller, which is more or less empty.

```
class RootPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home

  end
end
```

and the application_controller, perhaps this is useful:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 helper_method :current_order

 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 def current_order
  if !session[:order_id].nil?
    Order.find(session[:order_id])
  else
    Order.new
  end
 end

protected
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :postal,     :city, :street, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :postal,     :city, :street, :password, :remember_me) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :postal, :city, :street, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
   end
 end
```

And here is the root_pages/home.html.erb

```
  <h1>Willkommen bei Foodle!</h1>
```

and the application.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Foodle</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> 
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
 </head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-right">
      <h1 class="cart-text"><%= render 'layouts/cart_text' %></h1>
    </div>
   <%= yield %>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the _header.html.erb

```
<%= nav_bar fixed: :top, responsive: true do %>
  <%= menu_group do %>
    <%= menu_item "Foodle", root_path %>
    <%= menu_item "Bestellen", articles_path %>
    <%= menu_item "Alle Nutzer", users_path %>
  <% end %>

  <%= menu_group :pull => :right do %>
  <% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
    <%= menu_item "(Admin)" %>
  <% end %>
      <% if current_user %>
        <%= drop_down "Account" do %>
          <%= menu_item "Profil bearbeiten", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
          <%= menu_item "Passwort ändern", edit_user_registration_path(current_user) %>
          <%= menu_item "Abmelden", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
          <%= menu_item "Anmelden", new_user_session_path %>
          <%= menu_item "Registrieren", new_user_registration_path %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post your `root_pages` controller home action and view.  Almost certainly you're fetching something from the database and assigning it to an instance variable.  Your simple test doesn't create any objects so when it hits the database it won't find anything so the instance variable is nil.  In your code in the view I'm guessing you don't check if it's nil and just assume it will always exist.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your fast reaction, I added some information, i hope this helps to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you post the view for the home as well please.

Comment: So, more information added.

Comment: Can you run the test with the `-b` option and post the full stacktrace?  I can't see anything wrong with your code

Comment: Hmm, i can't post the full stacktrace because I reached the limit of characters  :-/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86773/discussion-between-kmmel-and-japed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the actual fix is to rename `application.css` to `application.scss`